# How to use a variable(string/integer/double) from code-behing to WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

How to use a variable(string/integer/double) from code-behing to WPF ?

For example, in my situation i have this Storyboard

```
          <Storyboard x:Key="volumerecdown">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.5" AccelerationRatio="0.5" DecelerationRatio="0.5" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="STRING_FROM_CODE_BEHIND"/>
          </Storyboard>
```

and where i STRING_FROM_CODE_BEHIND i want to be a variable or however is it name from code-behind

i tried to declare the string like this:

```
Public Property height_rec As String
```

but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You must use a property.

```
    Private _height_rec As Integer
    Public Property height_rec As Integer
    Get
        Return _height_rec
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _height_rec = value
    End Set
    End height_rec
```

and in xaml put this following :

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="volumerecdown">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.5" AccelerationRatio="0.5" DecelerationRatio="0.5" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="{Binding height_rec}"/>
          </Storyboard>
```

Comment: still doesn't work, had to replace  End height_rec  with  End Property, no errors, but the storyboard doesn't do anything